# User profile service combined with people search

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, people-search

The UserProfile service is started. How do I use this with people search to create 'staff profiles' on a page?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of steps you have to complete:

1. Create a new User Profile service application (you already did)
2. [Configure the Sync Connection with Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/manage-profile-synchronization)(Depending upon your requirement, ADI or MIM or 3rd party)
3. Create the Search Service Application
4. [Configure the People Search](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-configure-people-search-in-sharepoint-2013/)
5. Run the UPA Sync job( which import the profiles from AD)
6. Once it finished, you will see the profiles of every one.